# Multiple loading and unloading of PCI driver causes its /sys/bus/pci/devices/xxx directory to disappear

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I have a PCI driver for a FPGA card that installs and works fine.However, we have a need to clean up our system without rebooting which includes unloading this driver.

When starting again (without rebooting) the driver is re-installed. I have found that when I do this process (install/uninstall) multiple times, on the 5th unload of the driver the directory associated with the device just disappears.

`lspci` command can no longer find my device because of a bad link. I have to reboot to get the device directory (`/sys/bus/pci/devices/00000:04:00.0`) to show up again.

With some experimentation and reducing the driver down to the bare minimum I discovered that if I do not do a call to `pci_enable_device(..)` function in my `pci_probe_method`, then I am able to install/uninstall the driver multiple times without error.

Of course, I need to call this method before I can do anything with the device but I wanted to be sure it was not some other of the more complex initialization I am doing was causing the problem.

I have verified that my call to `pci_disable_device()` is being called in the `pci_remove_method()`. I should be able to enable and disable a PCI device indefinitely, right?  Any help in figuring out what is happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution to this problem was to eliminate an extraneous call I had to pci_dev_put(..).  I did not notice this before when submitting the question.  This was leftover from when this driver was not using the pci_probe() method to discover this device.  So, executing this call in the exit routine caused the structure for this device to go away after 5 calls.  So for now this problem is solved.